# Disable spell checker but keep suggestions

Tags: android

In Android, you can disable spell checking on an EditText by setting inputType to textNoSuggestions. I do that to get rid of the ugly red underlines below all the words in EditText that are not recognized. But this also disables the suggestions. What I really want is to disable the spell checker but still allow the user to have the suggestions show up above the keyboard. Is that possible?

You would think that this should be possible as most people tend to write stuff with a mixture of abbreviated/unknown words together with correctly spelled words. Being able to pick suggested words while not messing up the EditText with the ugly red underlines would be welcomed. If I really need spell checking, I could always just add a button that lets the user spell check their text.

Comment: adjust you device settings because famous option android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" also disables suggestions along with spell check

Answer (score 1):

android:inputType="textPhonetic"